# except one part of character class in python regex

Tags: python, regex

how can i except \d in below regex?

```
^[\d\w ]+$
```

it Matches strings with any words and digits and space characters. i want to change this to accept strings with any words and space characters.

i try below regex but it excepts digits and space too.

```
^[^\d\w ]+$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^(?:[^\W\d]| )+$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/88Dnsz/1). It can also be written as `^(?:(?!\d)[\w ])+$`.

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^\W\d]| )+` - 1 or more

  - `[^\W\d]` - chars other than non-word and digit chars
  - `|` - or
  - - whitespace
- `$` - end of string.

In `^(?:(?!\d)[\w ])+$`, `[\w ]` that may match any word and whitespace char, is restricted with `(?!\d)` lookahead and thus does not match digits.

Or, if you need ASCII only words:

```
^[a-zA-Z_ ]+$
```

Please bear in mind it will also allow underscores since `\w` matches `_` chars. If you do not need it, use `^(?:[^\W\d_]| )+$` / `^(?:(?![\d_])[\w ])+$` / `^[a-zA-Z ]+$`.

Comment: thanks. but, is there a way to accept just space character and except other whitespace characters like newline or tab?

Comment: @AlexMercer Just use a space instead of `\s`. Sorry for generalizing too much.